# Azure Front Door - Origin Group's Health probe

Tags: azure-front-door

Using the classic FD, the following Path for the Health probes was fine:
/api/status?code=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Updating FD to its latest iteration (Standard), for the same Function App backend, the Portal returned the following message:
"The probe path must start with /"

It seems that it doesn't like the "?" and "=" symbols in the entry (see image ): [portal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IctW.jpg)

Doers anyone know any way around this, and obviously the error message itself in incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a new portal related bug as I'm pretty sure I haven't had issues setting query string parameters in the probe path for AFD, but I was able to overcome this with Azure CLI.

`az afd origin-group update --origin-group-name "default-origin-group" --profile-name "afdprofile" --resource-group "myrg" --probe-path "/api/status?code=value"`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/afd/origin-group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-afd-origin-group-update

EDIT: This appears to have now been fixed in the portal:

[image]

Comment: It was mentioned that you are using AFD Classic, but Origin Groups are an AFD Std/Prem thing.  Also, I could only reproduce this error in AFD Std/Prem and not in AFD Classic.

I was going to revise the answer to use the correct Azure CLI commands for AFD Classic, but I believe you're actually using Standard or Premium.  Can you confirm?

Comment: I should have been more clearer, yes the issue is when using AFD Std/Premium (latest iteration) - so CLI works but Portal doesn't.  That's annoying, I'll put it s bug report to MS

Comment: Yeah the portal has been breaking some things lately for me.  For example a lot of times I can't assign an NSG to a subnet from the NSG resource because of an issue about the IP space in the subnet, but I can assign the NSG from the subnet blade of the VNET.

Comment: I reported it last week and it looks like it's been fixed.  Can you confirm on your end?

Comment: confirmed that it is now working, thanks for getting MS to fix this